# Running into string constant size limits in insert statements with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to copy a row from our production DB to my own little personal Oracle Express DB to repro a bug, since I can't really step into the code on production.  Unfortunately, this row involves a column that serializes some sort of data structure into a `blob` column type, laughing in the face of the normalization gods.  Here's the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO TPM_VIEWS VALUES(
5,
'Test Repro View',
665,
1,
'0001000000ffffffff01000000000000000c020000003a44414c2c205... //About 7600 characters
);
```

I've tried running this in Aqua Data Studio 10 and I get:

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

Next I tried pasting it into SQL*Plus, which gives me:

```
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
```

Lastly, I tried pasting the whole thing into foo.sql and ran `@foo.sql` which gives me:

```
SQL> @c:\foo.sql
Input truncated to 7499 characters
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

What's the super secret Oracle expert way to do this?  And no, I don't have access to the Oracle server itself so I can't run any command line backup or export utilities.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I also tried splitting apart the string by sprinkling some `' || '`'s around randomly, which gives me the error:

```
 ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

Comment: Can you log in to the production database?  Or are you saying that you can't even do that?

Comment: @JustinCave - Yup, I can run any SQL statement I want in Production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can access the production database, the simplest solution is probably to create a database link from your local XE database to the production database.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK link_to_prod
  CONNECT TO <<your user name in prod>> 
  IDENTIFIED BY <<your password in prod>>
  USING <<TNS alias for prod database>>
```

Then, you can copy the data from prod to your local database

```
INSERT INTO tpm_views
  SELECT <<list of columns including BLOB>>
    FROM tpm_views@link_to_prod
   WHERE <<some key>> = 5
```

Comment: Awesome!  That worked like a charm.  Are these links persistent, or do they get dropped automatically when I close the session?  I will have to remember this little trick for next time..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - The database link itself is a database object that will exist until you drop it.  The actual connection to the prod database will be closed when you close your session in the XE database.  If you want to close the connection to the prod database without closing your XE session, you can 'ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK link_to_prod` to close it.

Comment: Makes sense!  BTW, that 7k serialized string turned out to have encoded in it references to other database primary keys, and we changed the format of those primary keys in a recent upgrade.  Now we have to fix 117 of these BLOBs, hah!  How's that for bad database design..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - Good thing the database was properly normalized, eh?  What could possibly go wrong?